# How do I set a timestamp that updates daily on a website, with bootstrap and javascript, which could be useful for reviews and blogs etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm interested in setting up a timer/date stamp on my website, which uses Bootstrap, using JavaScript or whatever is necessary. Basically, when you see a review on somewhere like Google, or a blog post, underneath the photo of the person who made the post and their name, there's always a small bit of text that says how long ago it was written, such as '3 hours ago' or '1 month ago'. See the image below.

[image: example photo, for my timer/time stamp question]

How would I get something like this set up on an HTML/CSS/Bootstrap website, so that it automatically updates every day? For example, I would want it to say '1 hour ago' an hour after it was posted and '1 month ago' when a month has passed, automatically.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript would be necessary. I'd suggest starting with the static date and time of posting, then you can parse and rewrite that to a relative time if the client has JS enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking now of setting the static date and time of posting (as you mentioned) as a variable. Then, perhaps I could use the `Date()` function to collect the current date automatically, and compare the difference between the two

Comment: If you have a specific problem implementing that, give a [mcve]. Otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: In that case, I'll give it a go tomorrow and if it doesn't work, I'll provide an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple but inefficient way to do such a thing involves two parts:

1. Make a function that takes two timestamps and creates a string that says 'X time units ago`. You can find several libraries that do that easily.
2. Every once in a while (with `setInterval` every 30 seconds, for example), call that function with the arguments `Date.now()` and `websiteTimestamp` (assuming that's how you'd name your website's timestamp) and put the result in the appropriate view.

It would do lots of unnecessary overwrites, but isn't it simple? I mean it should be OK to show how old your page is, but probably bad to do in a chat app to show how old every chat message is.

Comment: Thanks! I came across something that appears to be quite useful. I'll post it as an answer to my question, since it is too long here.

Answer (score -1):

I just came across something like this from a previous post. Is this likely to do what I am looking for, updating automatically?

Also, what is the format of the 'date' input to the function (i.e. is it milliseconds, seconds etc. or a proper date format, such as YYYY-MM-DD)?

```
function timeSince(date) {

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

  var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " years";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " months";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " days";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " hours";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " minutes";
  }
  return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
}
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay)));
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay*2)));
```

Comment: I suggest you skipped "X seconds ago" and used "Less than a minute ago" instead, so that you won't have to run this too frequently.